# PyQGIS/PlugIn: How do I pre-check if processing function is executable before I get a QGIS critical error?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, pyqt

I built a PlugIn with the 'native:shortestpathpointtopoint' tool to find the shortest path between two points on a multipolyline. When I run the Plugin I want to get a message with information about wether the params are valid and the processing is actualliy feasable!

I can check the params for correct datatype, but how can i pre-check if the 'native:shortestpathpointtopoint' will actually work or not without getting a critical error. It wont work, when the two points are not connected by the polyline. I don't want a cryptic QGIS error but rather a: 'Pls check your points' messagebox.

I tried stuff like this but those are already pretty desperate tries:

```
def getPath(self):

    print('Pathfinder START')

    params = {
        'INPUT': lyr,
        'STRATEGY': 0,
        'TOLERANCE': 2,
        'START_POINT': self.Startpunkt,
        'END_POINT': self.Endpunkt,
        'OUTPUT': os.path.dirname(__file__) + '\\shortestPath\\shortestPath.shp'
    }
    if 'native:shortestpathpointtopoint'.canExecute():

        processing.run('native:shortestpathpointtopoint', params)

    else:
        print('Check your points')

    print('Pathfinder END')
```

Comment: Instead of `if ....canExecute() ... else:`, have you tried `try: processing.run(...) except my_error_type: print(....)` ?

Comment: yeah tried that before but didn't work. 

But somehow it works now! 

        try:
            processing.run('native:shortestpathpointtopoint', params)
            QMessageBox.information(None, ...')

        except:
            QMessageBox.critical(None, '...!')


This works perfectly!! So easy... thank you

Comment: So, can you post your valid code and description as answer please ? And welcome to GIS StackExchange.

Answer (score 3):

It works fine this way:

```
        try:
            processing.run('native:shortestpathpointtopoint', params)

        except:
            QMessageBox.critical(None, '...', '...!')
```